# Who knows the font in following website

Tags: fonts

I like the font of screenshot in this webpage http://wikieducator.org/PYTHON_TUTORIALS, (the font of Python code), and anyone can tell me the font name?

[image]

thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, didn't go through that entire page. Here's your desired font: **Akbar**.
[Read more about it here.](http://www.wobblymusic.com/groening/akbar.html)

PS: Really took time to find this one..

Comment: @fvu: I've edited the answer. Sorry, for that misunderstanding.

Comment: +1 for the determination to solve this question (and for the font's references, it's quite nice for certain contexts!)

Comment: Ecko， thanks very much!! I'v searched for much long time, and finally got it